# Integrating over an ellipsoid

Tags: integration, differential-geometry

This is the 3D follow-up question for the [2D version here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4702711/integrating-over-an-ellipse/4703297#4703297). I'm looking for a solution to the integral
$$
F(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{\pi/2} \delta(x - D(\theta,\phi)) \sin(\phi) \mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}\phi,
$$
where $\delta$ is the Dirac delta function and
$$
D(\theta,\phi) = a \sin(\theta) \sin(\phi) + b\cos(\theta) \sin(\phi) + c \cos(\phi)
$$
with $0 < a \leq b \leq c$. $D(\theta,\phi)$ is the summed coordinate of an ellipsoid (in the positive octant). $F(x)$ is then the probability distribution of $D(\theta,\phi)$.

I was able to solve the 2D version. Thus the integral can be rewritten to
$$
F(x) = \int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\gamma(x)}{\sqrt{\sin(\phi)^2(a^2 + b^2) - (x + c \cos(\phi))^2}} \sin(\phi) \mathrm{d} \phi,
$$
where
$$
\gamma(x) = \begin{cases} 
1 \textrm{ for } x < \max(a,b) \\
2 \textrm{ for } x \geq \max(a,b)
\end{cases}
$$
I'm uncertain about the correctness of the $\gamma$ function. Further, my attempts at the remaining integral become quickly unwieldy. I appreciate any hints on how to simplify the problem.

For an example, numerical integration yields this for $a = 1$, $b = 2$, $c = 3$
[image]